# Problemas ao serializar um form e fazer um Post da ViewModel usando Ajax - Asp.net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Estou fazendo um submit usando o AJAX, mas estou tendo problemas, pois está dando erro 404 e eu já tentei fazer de várias formas como usar o JSON.stringfy, usar [FromBody] na action da controller, etc. Alguém sabe me dizer o que está dando errado? Quando eu faço o submit normalmente (sem o uso do ajax), tudo funciona normalmente, mas com o ajax, parece haver algum problema na serialização e na forma com que eu passo o parâmetro (ViewModel).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

VIEWMODEL:

```
public class CriarParcelasAutomaticamenteViewModel
{
    public int FinanceiroId { get; set; }
    public int QuantidadeParcelas { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataPrimeiroVencimento { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorDocumento { get; set; }
}
```

CONTROLLER COMPLETA:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Retaguarda.Application.Interfaces;
using Retaguarda.Application.ViewModels.Financeiro.FinanceiroParcela;
using Retaguarda.Domain.Core.Notifications;

namespace Retaguarda.Presentation.Web.UI.MVC.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class FinanceiroParcelaController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly IFinanceiroParcelaAppService _financeiroParcelaAppService;
        private readonly ICriarParcelasAutomativamenteAppService _criarParcelasAutomativamenteAppService;

        public FinanceiroParcelaController(IFinanceiroParcelaAppService financeiroParcelaAppService,
                                 ICriarParcelasAutomativamenteAppService criarParcelasAutomativamenteAppService,
                                 INotificationHandler<DomainNotification> notifications) : base(notifications)
        {
            _financeiroParcelaAppService = financeiroParcelaAppService;
            _criarParcelasAutomativamenteAppService = criarParcelasAutomativamenteAppService;
        }
              

        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Policy = "CanWriteFinanceiroParcelaData")]
        [Route("financeiro-parcela-gerenciar/criar-financeiro-parcela-automaticamente/{financeiroId:int}")]
        public IActionResult CreateFinanceiroParcelaAutomaticamente(int financeiroId)
        {
            if (financeiroId == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(_criarParcelasAutomativamenteAppService.CreateNew(financeiroId));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Policy = "CanWriteFinanceiroParcelaData")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Route("financeiro-parcela-gerenciar/criar-financeiro-parcela-automaticamente/{financeiroId:int}")]
        public IActionResult CreateFinanceiroParcelaAutomaticamente(CriarParcelasAutomaticamenteViewModel criarParcelasAutomaticamenteViewModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(criarParcelasAutomaticamenteViewModel);

            var financeiroParcelasList = _financeiroParcelaAppService.CreateNewList(criarParcelasAutomaticamenteViewModel);
            if (financeiroParcelasList != null)
            {
                foreach (var financeiroParcela in financeiroParcelasList)
                {
                    int financeiroParcelaId = _financeiroParcelaAppService.Register(financeiroParcela);

                    if (!IsValidOperation())
                        return View(criarParcelasAutomaticamenteViewModel);
                }

                ViewBag.Sucesso = "Registros inseridos!";
            }

            return new EmptyResult();

            // return PartialView("~/Views/Financeiro/FinanceiroParcela/_FinanceiroParcelaGrid.cshtml", _financeiroParcelaAppService.CreateNewList(criarParcelasAutomaticamenteViewModel));
        }
    }
}
```

ACTION PROBLEMÁTICA:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Policy = "CanWriteFinanceiroParcelaData")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("financeiro-parcela-gerenciar/criar-financeiro-parcela-automaticamente/{financeiroId:int}")]
public IActionResult CreateFinanceiroParcelaAutomaticamente(CriarParcelasAutomaticamenteViewModel criarParcelasAutomaticamenteViewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(criarParcelasAutomaticamenteViewModel);

    var financeiroParcelasList = _financeiroParcelaAppService.CreateNewList(criarParcelasAutomaticamenteViewModel);
    if (financeiroParcelasList != null)
    {
        foreach (var financeiroParcela in financeiroParcelasList)
        {
            int financeiroParcelaId = _financeiroParcelaAppService.Register(financeiroParcela);

            if (!IsValidOperation())
                return View(criarParcelasAutomaticamenteViewModel);
        }

        ViewBag.Sucesso = "Registros inseridos!";
    }

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

AJAX:

```
$("#btn-criar-parcelas").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($('#frmCriarParcelasAutomaticamente').valid()) {
        //Desabilitar todos os elementos que estiverem bloqueados para poder efetuar o submit dos dados.
        $(':disabled').each(function (e) {
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        });

        var valdata = $("#frmCriarParcelasAutomaticamente").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/financeiro-parcela-gerenciar/criar-financeiro-parcela-automaticamente",
            type: "POST",
            //dataType: 'json',
            //contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            data: valdata,
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {              

            },
            error: function () {
                stopLoadModalInside();
                alert("Oops! Algo deu errado.");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Erro 404 significa No Found ou seja, não encontrado a sua rota depende do controler pelo visto qual é o seu controller?

Comment: @novic atualizei o Post com a Controller. Há duas actions com o mesmos nomes, mas possuem a mesma rota e com parâmetros diferentes. A segunda action é que preciso passar a viewmodel.

Comment: no `Route` coloque uma barra `(Route("/financeiro-parcela-gerenciar/criar-financeiro-parcela-automaticamente"))` teste os dois !

Comment: Não funcionou @novic :(

Comment: dá o mesmo erro

Comment: Sim, está dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: a sua rota ta errada: `/financeiro-parcela-gerenciar/criar-financeiro-parcela-automaticamente` deixa assim sem a variável no final agora vai no metodo com HttpPost

Comment: Sem a variável funcionou!! :) Aff, não acredito nisso!

Comment: funciona com a variavel também só que tem que passar? se quiser passar volta do jeito que era

Comment: se estava errando na rota ... tem que colocar igual está configurado.

Comment: Funciona sem a variável {financeiroId:int}. é que que tenho duas actions com a mesma rota e variável...

Comment: falta conhecimento pra você, você tem duas rotas iguais, mas, os verbos são diferentes uma é GET e a outra é POST isso também diferencias as rotas

Comment: Só que tem um problema: Quando a ViewModel é válida a action não deve retornar nada. Quando a viewmodel não é válida, ai sim, ela precisa retornar a viewmodel. Eu não sei como tratar isso... Eu estou usando  return new EmptyResult(); que faz dar erro na requisição ajax.. Vc saberia me dizer como tratar isso?

Comment: se já fez isso `if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(criarParcelasAutomaticamenteViewModel);`! então não sei o seu problema que é local

Comment: Deixa pra lá, eu resolvo isso depois. Se quiser comentar com a sua resposta que foi a retirada da variável {financeiroId:int}...te agradeço pela ajuda.